# RSS integration into Let's Chat

Tags: rss, xmpp

[Let's Chat](https://sdelements.github.io/lets-chat/) is a team communication tool, open source alternative to Slack.
I want the news of an RSS feed to be fed into a room inside Let's Chat.

**QUESTION:** Is there an free integration or plugin or third-party hack to achieve this?

https://github.com/sdelements/lets-chat/wiki/Plugins and https://github.com/sdelements/lets-chat/wiki/Integrations do not have that.
There is an [API to post messages](https://github.com/sdelements/lets-chat/wiki/API%3A-Messages#post-messages) so it is probably not that difficult to implement. Let's Chat seems to use XMPP so there might be a way to reuse an existing tool.

Requirements:

- Free
- Sends news as soon as possible, an hour delay is acceptable